# lambdas in xdocument query

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-xml

I am trying to migrate myself to C# from vb.net and am converting some of my projects to get a better understanding of the differences. I am having trouble converting the following Try-Catch code block ( The dim statements are there only for you to see the variable types, the try block is parsing a string representation of an xml document)as I am not sure how to use lambda expression in this scenario.

```
 Dim xmlResponse = XDocument.Parse(r)
 Dim gml = CType("http://www.opengis.net/gml", XNamespace)
 Dim ns = CType("http://www.hostip.info/api", XNamespace)
 Dim result As LocationInfo = Nothing  

Try
    result = (From x In xmlResponse.Descendants(ns + "Hostip") Select New LocationInfo() With {
                 .CountryCode = x.Element(ns + "countryAbbrev").Value,
                 .CountryName = x.Element(ns + "countryName").Value,
                 .Latitude = Single.Parse(x.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").[Single]().Value.Split(","c)(0)),
                 .Longitude = Single.Parse(x.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").[Single]().Value.Split(","c)(1)),
                 .CityName = Split(x.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")(0),
                 .State = Trim(Split(x.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")(1))
                    }).SingleOrDefault()
'Looks like we didn't get what we expected.
Catch nullEx As NullReferenceException
    'do something with nullEx here
End Try
```

**Update:**

Here is the first attempt with the suggestions from the first respondent. VS2013 shows errors. All the dot operators off x are in red (Element, Descendants) and select of "select new LocationInfo()" is also in red

```
 LocationInfo result = (from x in xmlResponse.Descendants(ns + "Hostip")
                             select new LocationInfo()
                                {
                                  CountryCode = x.Element(ns + "countryAbbrev").Value,
                                  Latitude = Single.Parse(x.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").First().Value.Split(',')[0]),
                                  Longitude = Single.Parse(x.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").First().Value.Split(',')[1]),
                                  CityName = string.Split(x.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")(0),
                                  State = string.Split(x.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")(1).Trim()
                                 }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I feel sorry for your troubles. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask one.

Comment: I edited the post to make a little more clear that I am having trouble converting the Try-Catch block to C#, thought it was fairly clear before the edit.

Comment: xmlResponse.Descendants(ns + "Hostip").Select(x => new LocationInfo{ set properties here.. })

Comment: @vishal... the problem lies in that when setting the properties, the x.Element and x.Descendants are red, and I'm not getting any help from VS2013 as to why. My original VB code worked fine

Comment: xmlResponse should be of type IEnumerable<XElement> , i wonder why u r not getting intellisense help from vs

Comment: solved that, resharper notes a possible nullrefexception on this line CountryCode = x.Element(ns + "countryAbbrev").Value , so i re wrote it as CountryCode = x.Element(ns + "countryAbbrev").Value != null ? x.Element(ns + "countryAbbrev").Value : "", which gave same problem even though that is a null check

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
           var tt = (from cc in xmlResponse.Descendants(ns + "Hostip")
                 select new LocationInfo()
                 {
                     CountryCode = cc.Element(ns + "countryAbbrev").Value,
                     Latitude = Single.Parse(cc.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").First().Value.Split(',')[0]),
                     Longitude = Single.Parse(cc.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").First().Value.Split(',')[1]),
                     CityName = Split(cc.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")[0],
                     State = Trim(Split(cc.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")[1])
                 }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: VS didnt like that, see my update in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't tag C# it's not clear if you want the answer in VB or C#.  These should work:

```
result = xmlResponse.Descendants(ns + "Hostip").Select(Function(x) New LocationInfo() With {
             .CountryCode = x.Element(ns + "countryAbbrev").Value,
             .CountryName = x.Element(ns + "countryName").Value,
             .Latitude = Single.Parse(x.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").[Single]().Value.Split(","c)(0)),
             .Longitude = Single.Parse(x.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").[Single]().Value.Split(","c)(1)),
             .CityName = Split(x.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")(0),
             .State = Trim(Split(x.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")(1))
                }).SingleOrDefault()

result = xmlResponse.Descendants(ns + "Hostip").Select(x => new LocationInfo{
             CountryCode = x.Element(ns + "countryAbbrev").Value,
             CountryName = x.Element(ns + "countryName").Value,
             Latitude = Single.Parse(x.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").[Single]().Value.Split(","c)(0)),
             Longitude = Single.Parse(x.Descendants(gml + "coordinates").[Single]().Value.Split(","c)(1)),
             CityName = Split(x.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")(0),
             State = Trim(Split(x.Element(gml + "name").Value, ",")(1))
                }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I thought I had tagged as C#, my apologies. The C# version you've provided solved the select issue but the Element and Descendants are still in red and the [Single] is outlined as an invalid struct

Comment: And the vb code I provided does work as expected, I'm just trying to convert it to C#

Comment: @dinotom - Have you added the namespace Xml  to your project? What error(s) does Intellisense report when you hover the mouse over the red lines?